# Is "adb root" the same as "adb shell" followed by "su"?

Tags: android, root

Sorry if this has been answered but couldn't find it. Can someone explain the difference between the two commands above. I have a rooted handset and can get a super user prompt by typing adb shell then su, but is adb root the same thing?